# parsley remote validation - include more data in request

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I have started using parsley.js for for validation and it is working great, just added more advanced validation that needs remote data, and got an issue. parsley-remote works fine, but it only send the data of that specific field to the server (title). In order to do my validation, I need also the data stored in the hidden field name="mcid". Can I manage this with parsley? Ideally a general approach that I can use for my entire application (large application, so keeping page specific code to a minimum).

My form (simplified):
    `<form>
    <input type="text" name="title" required="required" parsley-validation-remote="/Admin-Category/validateMainCategoryTitle/" data-validation-remote-method="POST"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mcid" value="2060"/>
    </form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up on my own question. Parsley is now release in v.2 and the new [parsley remote plugin](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/parsley.remote.html) has standard support for sending more parameter. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is an easy way to do it with the built-in Parsley remote validator - any possible solution would be a complicated workaround and you would be better off going with straight JavaScript to do it.

How is the value in the hidden field set? If I were doing this in Java, I would put the hidden field in the DTO or in the UpdateController so the value would be available to the `validateMainCategoryTitle` method. Is that possible with your application?

Alternatively, since you have both the values available on the form, can you write a custom parsley validation routine to check them, or do you need to go back to the server for some reason?

Comment: Thanks, believe you are right. The entire form is coming from the server with the values populated. The server could "remember" which mcid this is, using sessions I guess. Do not like it, but seems like the best approach.  Custom parsley validator would work as well, but keeping away from custom as much as possible. Then I need at least to make on generic one that I can use for all of these cases. Need to do some testing.